# Parsing this strange JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json

Can anyone tell me that how to retrieve URL element only from the first child of "thumbnail".Here is the json:

```
"thumbnail": [
      {
       "height": "49",
       "url": "http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/69340000/jpg/_69340597_8hxs1hvy.jpg",
       "width": "66"
      },
      {
       "height": "81",
       "url": "http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/69340000/jpg/_69340598_8hxs1hvy.jpg",
       "width": "144"
      }
     ]
```

Please help,I've tried everything from stdClass to JSON parsing but nothing seems to work out.Thanks.

**[EDIT]**:
The above json is an excerpt from a big json rss feed.I have managed to parse the json uptill this thumbnail node as follows:

```
$decoded_json->query->results->item->thumbnail
```

where $decoded_json is an object obtained after applying `json_decode()` function on the root of the json file.Now how to proceed past this `thumbnail` part?

Comment: `$var = json_decode($your_json); echo $var['thumbnail'][0]['url'];`

Comment: Actually this is an internal part of a big json file.The tree is like this:
$decoded_json->query->results->item->thumbnail

Comment: @cale_b should be `$var['thumbnail'][0]->url` unless you pass `true` as the second argument, which tells it to create an associative array instead of stdClass.

Comment: `echo json_decode($your_json,true)['thumbnail'][0]['url'];` will work in up-to-date versions ;)

Comment: to go past thumbnail you do `$decoded_json->query->results->item->thumbnail[0]->url` since thumbnail is an array just access it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$JsonObj = json_decode($JsonString);
if( $JsonObj === NULL ) {
   echo "Malformed JSON string or Recursion limit reached";
}
print $JsonObj[0]->url;
```

if the json file is too big you might hit the recursion limit. The default is 512 in 5.3, 128 in 5.2.3, and 20 in previous versions. you can set the recursion depth as the third argument

```
json_decode($JsonString,false,1024);
```

The second argument is a boolean, true if you want an associative array made, false(default) if instead  you want an stdClass object.

**[EDIT]**

To go past thumbnail you do `$decoded_json->query->results->item->thumbnail[0]->url` since thumbnail is an array just access it as such. 
More than likely you will want to loop over it like

```
foreach($decoded_json->query->results->item->thumbnail as $thumbnail) {
   echo $thumbnail->url;
}
```

Comment: Your edited part contains the solution.Thank you very much :)